# Setting fetchmode in NHibernate is not eliminating SELECT N+1 issue

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm struggling with something fairly basic.  I have a one-to-many relationship and I'm setting the fetchmode to inner join in my Criteria query.  I see the resulting SQL includes the join, but it also lazily fetches the child entities.  What am I doing wrong?

Mappings (Industry has many Manufacturers):

```
public class IndustryMap : ClassMap<Industry>
{
    public IndustryMap()
    {
        Id(industry => industry.ID);
        Map(industry => industry.Name);

        HasMany(x => x.Manufacturers)
            .KeyColumn("IndustryID")
            .AsSet()
            .Access.PascalCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class ManufacturerMap: ClassMap<Manufacturer>
{
      public ManufacturerMap()
      {
          Id(manufacturer=> manufacturer.ID);
          Map(manufacturer => manufacturer.Name);

          References(manufacturer => manufacturer.Industry, "IndustryID")
              .LazyLoad();
      }
}
```

Query:

```
var industries = this.Session.CreateCriteria<Industry>()
                                .CreateAlias("Manufacturers", "manu", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                                .AddOrder(new Order("Name", true))
                                .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
                                .List<Industry>();
```

Resulting SQL from NHProf (I would expect statement #1 to be the only statement):

```
-- statement #1
SELECT   this_.Id           as Id5_1_,
         this_.LastUpdated  as LastUpda2_5_1_,
         this_.Name         as Name5_1_,
         manu1_.Id          as Id6_0_,
         manu1_.LastUpdated as LastUpda2_6_0_,
         manu1_.Name        as Name6_0_,
         manu1_.IndustryID  as IndustryID6_0_
FROM     Dealer.[Industry] this_
         inner join Dealer.[Manufacturer] manu1_
           on this_.Id = manu1_.IndustryID
ORDER BY this_.Name asc

-- statement #2
SELECT manufactur0_.IndustryID  as IndustryID1_,
       manufactur0_.Id          as Id1_,
       manufactur0_.Id          as Id6_0_,
       manufactur0_.LastUpdated as LastUpda2_6_0_,
       manufactur0_.Name        as Name6_0_,
       manufactur0_.IndustryID  as IndustryID6_0_
FROM   Dealer.[Manufacturer] manufactur0_
WHERE  manufactur0_.IndustryID = '529fde0e-dccf-456a-ab69-4a4b662aa0d2' /* @p0 */

-- statement #3
SELECT manufactur0_.IndustryID  as IndustryID1_,
       manufactur0_.Id          as Id1_,
       manufactur0_.Id          as Id6_0_,
       manufactur0_.LastUpdated as LastUpda2_6_0_,
       manufactur0_.Name        as Name6_0_,
       manufactur0_.IndustryID  as IndustryID6_0_
FROM   Dealer.[Manufacturer] manufactur0_
WHERE  manufactur0_.IndustryID = '529fde0e-dccf-456a-ab69-4a4b662aa0d3' /* @p0 */

-- statement #4
SELECT manufactur0_.IndustryID  as IndustryID1_,
       manufactur0_.Id          as Id1_,
       manufactur0_.Id          as Id6_0_,
       manufactur0_.LastUpdated as LastUpda2_6_0_,
       manufactur0_.Name        as Name6_0_,
       manufactur0_.IndustryID  as IndustryID6_0_
FROM   Dealer.[Manufacturer] manufactur0_
WHERE  manufactur0_.IndustryID = '529fde0e-dccf-456a-ab69-4a4b662aa053' /* @p0 */

-- statement #5
SELECT manufactur0_.IndustryID  as IndustryID1_,
       manufactur0_.Id          as Id1_,
       manufactur0_.Id          as Id6_0_,
       manufactur0_.LastUpdated as LastUpda2_6_0_,
       manufactur0_.Name        as Name6_0_,
       manufactur0_.IndustryID  as IndustryID6_0_
FROM   Dealer.[Manufacturer] manufactur0_
WHERE  manufactur0_.IndustryID = '529fde0e-dccf-456a-ab69-4a4b662aa245' /* @p0 */
```

Answer (score 3):

I have reproduced your scenario with a few minor changes and the result is as expected. Check the following:

Domain classes:

```
public class Industry
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Industry Industry { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class IndustryMap : ClassMap<Industry>
{
    public IndustryMap()
    {
        Id(industry => industry.ID);
        Map(industry => industry.Name);

        HasMany(x => x.Manufacturers)
            .KeyColumn("IndustryID")
            .AsSet()
            .Inverse()
            //.Access.PascalCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class ManufacturerMap : ClassMap<Manufacturer>
{
    public ManufacturerMap()
    {
        Id(manufacturer => manufacturer.ID);
        Map(manufacturer => manufacturer.Name);

        References(manufacturer => manufacturer.Industry, "IndustryID")
            .LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

Query:

```
var industries = session.CreateCriteria<Industry>()
                .SetFetchMode("Manufacturers", FetchMode.Eager) //this is it
                            .List<Industry>();
```

UPDATE:

Query ordering by Manufacturers.Name:

```
var industries = session.CreateCriteria<Industry>()                          
                    .SetFetchMode("Manufacturers", FetchMode.Eager) //this is it
                      .CreateAlias("Manufacturers","manu")
                      .AddOrder(Order.Asc("manu.Name")
                                .List<Industry>();
```

Comment: I reproduced your changes in my code step-by-step and it does appear that the .SetFetchMode was the difference.  What's the difference between .SetFetchMode and .CreateAlias?  I was under the impression that they should do the same thing.

Comment: CreateAlias allows you to add criteria to a related entity, similar to a join in a table, the "FetchMode" in the CreateAlias method is only to ensure that it will be an Inner Join or Left Outer Join. SetFetchMode tells NHibernate to treat the property lazily or eagerly.

Comment: Whoa.  Big lightbulb just went off.  Not to look a gift horse in the mouth, but how could I add an order statement to that same query on Manufacturer.Name?

Comment: I copied your query code and the CreateAlias line triggers N+1 when I navigate through the records.  When I comment out the CreateAlias and AddOrder it works perfectly.